# Not able to install scipy, matplotlob and scikit-learn using pip 1.5.6

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, matplotlib, scikit-learn, pip

Trying to install

```
pip install numpy
pip install scipy
pip install matplotlib
pip install scikit-learn
```

> It failed with scipy, matplotlib and scikit-learn. 
>   (from https://pypi.python.org/simple/scipy/) because it is not compatible with this Python
>       Skipping

My python version is 3.4 and pip version is 1.5.6 
please help me install those above package

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With pip 1.5.6 it will try to compile those projects from source which requires a lot of system dependencies (especially for scipy, you need gfortran and an optimized BLAS/LAPACK implementation).

I assume you are using the system provided version of pip under Linux. I would recommend to either use the latest version of pip (8.1 or later) in an a virtualenv (to avoid replacing the files of the system installed version of pip). Then you should be able to install manylinux wheels which do not require the compilation step.

Alternatively you can install miniconda and install those packages with the `conda` command line instead of pip.

Comment: Thank you Ogrisel. Well, I am using windows 8 and python 3.4, I have already start most of my work in nltk in python. When I wanted this scikit, I got all this bugs asking for LAPACK etc.. (It said no folder or file of Lapack found in site-package/lib/). Please help me how to install step by step in windows 8 so that I can work with scikit-learn

Comment: On windows it's probably easier to just use the Anaconda distribution. It comes with scikit-learn included.

Comment: I already have python 3.4 installed, If I download the python from anaconda distribution now, will it not conflict ?

Comment: No it will install its own python in its own folder and will be independent of anything else on the system.

Comment: If for some reason you really really want to use your own Python version instead of using anaconda, you can download windows wheels from http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/ and use pip to install them (from the downloaded files).

Comment: thank you very much, this helped me a lot. But just the last thing anaconda 4.2.0 has python 3.5 in it, I am using 3.4 just because I got libraries to connect to MySQL however, I found it very difficult to get a library for 3.5 which can connect to MySQL DB, can u please tell me whats the version of anaconda for python 3.4 and over all this if we have a library for 3.5 which can connect to MySQL DB please guide me.

Answer (score -1):

Forget shitty `pip`, which is flawed beyond repair (static linking etc.)

Download IPython with the Anaconda Suite.... https://www.continuum.io/downloads

It brings most of the needed modules for scientific computing (as it is a crappy task if you have to download stuff to site-packages and run python setup.py install 3781 times..)

I wrote several programs using matplotlib, scipy, numpy etc with it..

Moreover it sports module package manager (comparable to Synaptic on Ubuntu..) if you are to lazy for the above mentioned task (and you are..).

Greets Dr. Cobra